# $\sigma$-additivity of Lebesgue measure.

Tags: lebesgue-measure

Can one show that Lebesgue measure is $\sigma$-additive on using only its definition which is $\lambda^n ([a,b))= \prod_{i=1}^n(b_i-a_i)$ and the fact that the set of semi-open boxes form a semi-ring? I saw a proof in a book which relies way too heavily on handwavery which isn't particularly helpful as I'm self studying the material.

Comment: σ-additivity is more like an *axiom* which we want our measure to obey. The definition you quote only defines the Lebesgue measure of $n$-boxes whose sides are parallel to the coordinate axes, as it seems. But the requirement that our measure shall be σ-additive leads to the measure being defined on a much richer category of shapes, for example solid polyhedra and balls, and all open sets, and more.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen the book I'm going through uses Caratheodory's theorem to extend lebesgue measure, so all one needs to achieve that is to show $\lambda$ is a pre-measure and the set of $n$-boxes is a semi-ring . The theorem then guaranties the existence of an extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One defines $\lambda^n$ on intervals as shown, then extends by finite additivity to finite disjoint unions of intervals, which form a semi-ring.  To continue the extension, we need to show that result is "countably additive"..., that is, if an element $B$ of the sigma-ring happens to equal a countable disjoint union of other elements $A_k$, then the series converges to the value: $\lambda^n(B) = \sum_k \lambda^n(A_k)$.  So first reduce to proving the case where $B$ is an interval and the sets $A_k$ are intervals.  Then the proof will proceed (using the Heine-Borel theorem) by reducing to the case of a finite union.  And that last case has to be done by some combinatorics.

Comment: The proof you are mentioning is the one I read however it made no sense and I felt like it had many gaps, here is the question I posed about it:http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/630262/about-the-proof-that-lebesgue-measure-is-a-premeasure
Is the proof you are talking about the same one?

Comment: That's the one.  To write it out in enough detail for beginners takes a few pages.  And the Heine-Borel step is important, since all the rest would work in $\mathbb Q^n$, where this result fails.

Comment: Do you happen to know a place were I could find it(a detailed proof)? I've searched several times without any results.

Comment: Maybe Royden, *Real Analysis*.  It's in its 4th edition, so maybe has the arguments in smoothed out form.

Comment: Found it! Section 20.2. Thank you!

Comment: Minor remark: To obtain a semi-ring, you do not actually have to extend to the finite disjoint unions of intervals; it suffices to take all intervals of the form $[a,b)$.