# Relation between sets on a semi-rings

Tags: elementary-set-theory

How can one given rectangles a union of disjoint rectangles in $\Bbb R^{n+1}$(more specifically in $\mathcal J^n $ ): $\bigsqcup_{j \in \Bbb{N}}I^{n+1}_j=\bigsqcup_{j \in \Bbb{N}}(I_j^1 \times I_j^n)$  decompose them like this:

$$I=\bigsqcup_{j \in \Bbb{N}}(I_j^1 \times I_j^n)=\text{why?}\bigsqcup_{k \in \Bbb{N}}\bigsqcup_{l \in \Bbb{N}}(\widetilde{I}_k^1 \times \widetilde{I}_l^1)=\bigsqcup_{k \in \Bbb{N}}\widetilde{I}_k^1 \times \bigsqcup_{l \in \Bbb{N}}\widetilde {I}_l^n \in \mathcal J^1 \times \mathcal J^n$$

Using the fact that $\mathcal J^n$ is a semi-ring. The $\widetilde{I}$ are different from the $I$'s? The last equality is easy but the first one I can't get. For more details on where these $\widetilde{I}$ should come from see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/630262/about-the-proof-that-lebesgue-measure-is-a-premeasure). I can't relate however the previous steps(in the question) to this.

Notation: $\sqcup$ is disjoint union, $I$ and $\widetilde{I}$ are rectangles (sets of the form $[a,b)$), $\mathcal J^n$ is the collection of all rectangles it is also a [semi-ring](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Semiring_of_Sets).